# Print works only on administrator account

Tags: printing, non-admin, windows-server-2019

I am using a Windows server 2019. I added a local port directed to a local address. If I print through the Administrator account, print works successfully but if I print through other account, it gives error on printing.

I gave administrator rights to other accounts too but no result. I opened notepad by right clicking and opening notepad as administrator but still gives error on printing. Gave full rights to every user.

How to start printing? It does not specifies the error but eventually leads to printer in error state.

Comment: What error did you receive exactly?  Edit your question, please do not submit a comment, to include this vital information.

Comment: added in the question...

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Can you be more specific and detailed on what exactly you have done to grant the "admin rights to the other accounts". Can you explain how you defined this local printer and directed it to a local address? If you can be more specific and clear, someone could help you resolve this soon.

Comment: Adding a screenshot of the error message will help.

Comment: There is just a simple notification saying error while printing

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Have you granted `authenticated users` print access ? Is this server in a domain environment? Is it only local accounts that sign onto the Server 2019 that have this issue? Wasn't sure if sharing the printer and then mapping it that way on the other accounts make any difference as a share with the share and printing permissions assigned accordingly to allow such access. Can you tell the specifics about the make and model of the locally attached printer which you have trouble with, just in case that matters?

Comment: While still waiting on feedback.... Have you already deleted the printer, uninstalled all drivers, cleaned up any printer settings definitions, rebooted, reinstalled the printer drivers, redefine the local configuration, etc.? Rule out the simple stuff first, have you already done this sort of thing? Have you read over my previous comments, can you please provide some feedback or do a simple [edit] to clearly indicate something further than you already put on the question? It seems a bit too broad really so start narrowing down and tell what you determined thus far in your troubleshooting.

Comment: Another thought is to find the location where the print jobs spool up and such and ensure it a location that all users can print to. This seems to be the most logical explanation since it prints fine for admin but others that are "locally" logged on printing to the same local printer cannot. Perhaps those accounts cannot access the print spooling folder you can see from the printer via **`Server Properties` | `Advanced` | `Spool`** and see the folder path. Consider changing or allow others access to this location. I have more ideas too but you provide no feedback making it harder to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the server. The IP address which the local port was directed to, refused to take print commands of non-administrator accounts. I just solved the problem changing User account settings on the PC with which printer was connected to.

Answer (score 1):

If Server 2019 still includes the
[The print server security user interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj190062(v%3Dws.11)#the-print-server-security-user-interface):

- Run Print Management
- Click Print Servers
- Right-click the print server and select Properties
- Click the Security tab
- Verify that Everyone is allowed Print:

[image]

- Check also the Advanced permissions:

[image]

(Screenshots taken on a Windows Server 2016 virtual machine *without an attached printer*.)

Comment: Already done that harrymc. Everyone is given all permissions.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2019, many printing functions can be disabled for normal/adminstrative privileged users. This can be because of a group/domain policy. Is there any reason to have to print off of other user accounts? If not, you should be able to just print off the Administrator account.

If other users are using the machine, you could have them send it to a separate machine with print access, send it to the Administrator account, or send it to themselves to print later.

Did this issue start happening after you added this port? If so, does user account printing work when you remove it? I don't see why such port would affect this, unless it was created on the same pathway as the printer...

Answer (score -1):

You should never give any other user administrative privileges unless they are getting paid to administrate.
You can make a new group that is specific to the printer and add them to this group.  You then add new printers to this group and new users who need to print.  Not everyone needs to print, nor on every printer.  So multiple printer groups may be required.

Comment: What if they are volunteering to administrate? What if this server's company says everyone should be able to print?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Administrative permissions shouldn't be needed to print at all, if they are, there's something wrong already.

Comment: If it doesn't matter if it gets borked up then so be it.  Printers are devices that require access parameters, just like users do.  You should be able to configure it so anybody can print.  But it isn't windows xp.  It isn't 'admin' permissions, it is printing permissions, access to the printer.  When you set the printer up you make it 'public' or whatever you like.  Up to you.